# How can I get executable filename from core file in HPUX?

Tags: gdb, executable, coredump, hp-ux

I couldn't find any answer for this question from stackoverflow.com yet.

```
% uname -a
HP-UX rx3600 B.11.31 U ia64 2782985371
```

In linux, I can get the filename from a core dump file as below.
"gserver" is the executable binary filename I'm looking for here.

```
% file ./core.4837
./core.4837: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from 'gserver --shared 1 --msgqkey=22581'
```

But, I got a different output of "file" command in HPUX, which has no executable filename matching the core.

```
% file ./core.10496
./core.10496: ELF 64-bit MSB core file IA-64, version 1 (HP-UX)
```

Is there any way to get it?

Comment: Does GDB print the correct executable name when you load the core file?

Comment: Will this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354988/how-to-get-full-path-of-executable-from-a-core-dump-file-in-hpux

Answer (score 0):

@anorm
Thanks.

Here is my output of pldd command.

```
% pldd ./core.10496
error obtaining loadmap address from gmaster
file may not be a shared IPF executable
```

Maybe I can get a hint from here.
"gmaster" is my executable binary filename.